# Django : null value in column "id" of relation violates not-null constraint

Tags: python, django, postgresql, api, django-rest-framework

I want to post data into my model in raw format. but every time I post data and pass the foreign key it returns null. I don't know why I tried everything. I passed the column as `series: 2` and `series_id:2` nothing's working. i don't know what i'm doing wrong.

**This is my ViewSet**

```
class SeasonViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Season.objects.all()
    permission_classes = [
        permissions.AllowAny
    ]
    serializer_class = SeasonSerializer
```

**Serializers.py**

```
class SeasonSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    series = StringRelatedField()
    class Meta:
        model = Season
        fields = '__all__'
```

**Here's my model:**

```
class Season(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    number = models.IntegerField()
    series = models.ForeignKey(Series, related_name="seasons", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    artwork_vr = models.ImageField(upload_to="images/tv", blank=True, default="default/default_video.png")
    premiereDate = models.DateField(blank=True)
    endDate = models.DateField(blank=True)
```

**This is how I'm posting data to API**

```
    {
        "series": 2,
        "name": "Attack",
        "number": 2,
        "premiereDate": "2021-07-03",
        "endDate": "2021-07-03"
    }
```

**and I get this error :**
`null value in column "series_id" of relation "tvshow_season" violates not-null constraint DETAIL:  Failing row contains (38, null, 4, default/default_video.png, 2021-07-03, , 2021-07-03).`

---

Comment: Maybe try PrimaryKeyRelatedField instead? I think StringRelatedField is read-only.

Comment: You need to update your question to include version of Django being used as well as the fact that the serializer is coming from Django REST Framework(also version of same). To me it seems you need to remove `series = StringRelatedField()`.  The ` fields = '__all__'` will include the `id` field.

Answer (score 0):

Change this line

```py
series = StringRelatedField()
```

to this

```py
series = PrimaryKeyRelatedField(queryset=Series.objects.all())
```

So you could post your data API that way.